# How to delete sent selenium keys python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I tried instagram login with selenium library with python3,

```
email = input("Enter your email> ")
password = input("Enter your password> ")
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/")
driver.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys(email)
driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys(password)
login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']")
login_button.click()
```

Then I want to add function, when the login credentials are incorrect, let user re-enter them again,
I want to do it without refreshing the page, doing something like .send_keys(keys.delete)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options. I shall list two of them.

**1. Sending the backspace key**

To send the backspace key, or most other keys for that matter, you can use the Keys enum in the selenium.common.webdriver.keys module. 
i.e., you can do something like:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
...
...
driver.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys(Keys.BACK_SPACE)
```

**2. Clearing the textfield itself**

Of course, a much easier method would be to just clear the textfield using the clear() method

So essentially:

```
driver.find_element_by_name("username").clear()
driver.find_element_by_name("password").clear()
```

You can read more about Keys and clear() here (Ctrl-f it):
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html

(Checking if the username/password is invalid is also covered on this page)

Comment: Thanks, really! Dont you know how to make it detect if the credentials were sucessful?

Comment: @StackAdminsAreDicksChris of course, according to the documentation link I sent, you can check for the presence of an error string in the page source to see if the credentials are wrong. E.g. 
`if "password was incorrect" in driver.page_source:`

Don't forget to mark this answer as accepted if it helped you. :)